# Model Method with a Variable

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following view that takes the value of "q" from a template:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from GOTHAMWEB.GRID.models import *

def search(request):
    errors = []
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET['q']
        if not q:
            errors.append('Enter a search term.')
        elif len(q) > 20:
            errors.append('Please enter at most 20 characters.')
        else:
            srvr = Server.objects.filter(name__icontains=q)
        return render_to_response('search_results.html',
                {'srvr': srvr, 'query': q})

    return render_to_response('search_form.html',
        {'errors': errors})
```

Is it possible to pass the value of q from the view to a model method, such as "server='q' " below.  I have tried this but is fails.  Before concluding it cannot be done, will someone please tell me for certain.

```
class MemoryManager(models.Manager): 
    def get_query_set(self): 
        return super(MemoryManager, self).get_query_set().filter(server='q')
```

Comment: Is MemoryManager set as the primary manager in your Server model (e.g., "objects = MemoryManager")? You'd have to modify get_query_set to accept parameters, either one param (q) or a set of arguments. Why not make a separate method on the manager for these calls?

Comment: No, it's the second: #1  objects = models.Manager() #2  memsinserver = MemoryManager()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not at all clear what you are trying to do here. In the function, you are filtering on the value of the GET variable `q`. But in the Manager, you are filtering on the **string** `"q"`.

Did you just want to pass the value of `q` into the Manager? If so, the easiest way would be to define a separate Manager method:

```
class MemoryManager(models.Manager):
    def filter_server(q):
        return self.get_query_set().filter(server=q)
```

Now you can call `Server.memsinserver.filter_server(q)`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for.